# Creating and moving graphic objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics

I am planning a Javascript application that lets the user draw dots on the screen and move them around by dragging. Whenever the user creates or moves a dot, the application automatically draws squares between the dots.

What Javascript library or JQuery plugin is designed for such applications?

Comment: I see now that there is a duplicate question: stackoverflow.com/questions/5882716/html5-canvas-vs-svg-vs-div/5895577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is a technology for vector graphics in the browser - with events such as mouse click, drag, etc...

two popular libraries:

Raphael.js:  http://raphaeljs.com/

Snap: http://snapsvg.io/about/

Comment: Thanks. Snap.js looks like the best option.